# What's the difference between вернуться and вернусь?

Tags: разница

What's the difference between вернуться and вернусь? 
Many times I'm confused between these two.

For example:

> I'm coming back home.  Я **вернуться** / **вернусь** домой.

Answer (score 6):

Вернуться is an infinitive " to return,to come back".

> Он улетел, но обещал вернуться (He has flown away, but promised to return.

Вернусь is a future tense, first person,singular

> Я вернусь домой.

Comment: Thank you gor the answer.  So if we are comparing it to present progressive in English,  I'm coming back home right now. Which of these 2 forms is the correct?

Comment: @Influx **вернуться** is an infinitive **to return/come back** you may have confused with present tense **возвращаюсь** which can be used to denote an act planned for the future just like in English - **Завтра я возвращаюсь домой** - **Tomorrow i'm coming back home**... as for the present per se, Russian doesn't have continuous mode, so it's always **возвращаюсь/ешься/ется/емся/ются**